Deserializing Anchor Account Data
The IDL from anchor is this
 {
  "name": "GlobalVotes",
  "type": {
    "kind": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "tremp",
        "type": "u32"
      },
      {
        "name": "boden",
        "type": "u32"
      }
    ]
  }
},

And when I run

anchor account vote_info.GlobalVotes 7uGibYhUzB8mrLvHqR6uSZotmnuSQTFtMfrTcDDD5Sq3

it returns the appropriate information deserialized from the account. However, I am trying to pull this account info from outside of the anchor environment (in a react front end app) and when  I try to use Borsh I cannot deserialize the data correctly/at all. How do I deserialize using the Anchor IDL/ fill in the appropriate schema for something like borsh and deserialize the account data from the client side outside of anchor environment?

I haven’t tested anything but I’ve been researching and I think it comes down to anchor putting 8 bytes of discriminator data at the start of account data, so I’m going to slice the first 8 bytes off the account data received and then try the schema again with Borsh.
